# Not able to access jenkins from browser

Tags: jenkins

I am running jenkins on a VM hosted on a server.I am trying to access it through my browser but not able to do it.

I run jenkins server using java -jar jenkins.war.Below is the output of jenkins server.When I try to access it through browser I get "This site can’t be reached".

What could be the issue.I was able to access it through browser 2 days back but now I am not able to

```
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:37 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log initialized
INFO: Logging initialized @770ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:37 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:37 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler setContextPath
WARNING: Empty contextPath
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:38 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
INFO: jetty-9.4.z-SNAPSHOT; built: 2019-02-15T16:53:49.381Z; git: eb70b240169fcf1abbd86af36482d1c49826fa0b; jvm 1.8.0_212-8u212-b03-0ubuntu1.16.04.1-b03
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:38 PM org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor visitServlet
INFO: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:38 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager doStart
INFO: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:38 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager doStart
INFO: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:38 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HouseKeeper startScavenging
INFO: node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
Jenkins home directory: /home/puneet/.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:39 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler doStart
INFO: Started w.@2f67a4d3{Jenkins v2.176.2,/,file:///home/puneet/.jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}{/home/puneet/.jenkins/war}
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:39 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector doStart
INFO: Started ServerConnector@769a1df5{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:39 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
INFO: Started @2754ms
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:39 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v4.0 running: controlPort=disabled
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:41 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:41 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:49 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:49 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:50 PM hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$FaultTolerantScope$1 error
INFO: Failed to instantiate optional component hudson.plugins.build_timeout.operations.AbortAndRestartOperation$DescriptorImpl; skipping
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:51 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:51 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:51 PM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Started Download metadata
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:51 PM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Finished Download metadata. 4 ms
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:51 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@b163c5d: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Fri Aug 16 14:40:51 IST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:51 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@b163c5d]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@17f02947
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:51 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@17f02947: defining beans [authenticationManager]; root of factory hierarchy
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:52 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@2afefb71: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Fri Aug 16 14:40:52 IST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:52 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@2afefb71]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@36319ffa
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:52 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@36319ffa: defining beans [filter,legacy]; root of factory hierarchy
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:52 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Aug 16, 2019 2:40:52 PM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
```

Comment: It's saying fully up and runnings. if you are trying to access it using the public IP of the server, kindly check if it has changed?

Comment: Have checked and the public ip is same